# First paid gig as an amateur; do I need insurance?

Tags: amateur, insurance

I've had previous gigs for organisations on a very informal basis, and now one of them wants to book me for a higher profile event and has indicated they want to pay.

The money really isn't the issue for me, as the organisation in question is a community one. But I wonder whether if I'm being paid I should step up to the plate r.e. insurance.

I hear of professionals having liability insurance and indemnity insurance, but I'm not sure what's relevant for me. Can someone shed light on this? I'm in the UK if that helps.

Comment: By the way, _by definition_, if you are being paid, then you are a professional (ignoring the other senses of how "professional" is used). Congratulations!

Comment: ^^ I thought the definition was someone who makes a living from XXXX would be considered a professional, not just being paid for odd-jobs

Comment: The road to being a professional is gilded by paid odd-jobs, at least in my experience. Congrats, Dan!

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft those are just well-paid professionals. Or perhaps *successful* professionals. Or even hard-working professionals.

Comment: Not an answer, because I have only one anecdotal data point as an example: I heard of a case when a wedding photographer's memory card malfunctioned and he lost all the photos. He was the only photographer at the event. The newlyweds were not amused.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft there's no brightline definition of when one is "officially" considered professional, but here's my heuristic: If the odd job is taxable (and basically, they _all_ are), and especially if your personal wealth/property could be jeopardized due to a liability situation in the course of performing the odd job, then i'd consider that being a professional. =)

Comment: We're at the risk of turning this into a chat thread :-), so best just agree to disagree!! I do an amount of paid photography, but certainly do not consider myself a professional, as it is not my main income.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. Presuming you're working as freelancer. Without a doubt. Regardless of how much you're being paid, or if you're not being paid (such as if you work with models). If you're employed rather than freelance then the company's existing insurances will probably protect you, but make sure to check.

Professional indemnity insurance protects you from any claims of inadequate service to the client.

Public liability insurance should be purchased as well in case someone injures themself and it's considered your fault. Such as if someone trips over your camera bag, or a lightstand falls on them and they try to sue.

These insurances will provide cover for the legal costs and expenses in your defence as well as compensation payable if they win any payout. They can be picked up alongside equipment insurance (Photoguard and Aaduki are two commonly seen names).

At the same time I recommend getting your camera gear insured as well if it isn't already. Depending on the gig of course, the last thing you want is someone spilling a drink and you have to foot the repair bill or buy new equipment to replace it.

Comment: Down voter. Rather than just DV'ing can you provide reasoning why so I can improve my answer?.

Comment: To reiterate - ***Without a doubt***.  If you can't afford the premiums (which aren't likely to be much anyways), you *certainly* can't afford to pay a claim/defense if a suit is brought against you for anything.

Comment: If my lightstand falls on someone, can't they sue anyway even if I'm not a professional?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev yes. Thats why insurance is worth having if youre not a professional or being paid.

Answer (score 7):

Legally need? - No.

In reality - It's a good idea, but depends on a few factors
such as if you are going to be doing this a lot, are you using expensive equipment? does anything you do or can do affect safety of others? 
If you screw up or your camera dies, is it s big issue for the client?

Or are you just walking around taking a few candid snaps?

You have 4 basic types:

- Public liability covers you if your lighting falls on a baby etc.
- Professional indemnity covers loss to your client if you fail to deliver etc.
- Employer's liability covers any staff you may have (not applicable here)
- Equipment cover is obvious.

Comment: Depending on the location of the shoot, there _could_ be legal requirements for insurance, or permits (which will require insurance).

Comment: I can't think of any circumstances where it would be a LEGAL requirement, it may well be a policy requirement or a requirement to get the job, but legal... not sure. Can you name any @BraddSzonye? (out of interest)

Comment: Outdoor shoots in many cities legally require a permit, which in turn requires insurance. For example, outdoor photography in San Francisco requires “$1 million ($2 million aggregate) of General Liability, $1 million of Auto Liability, $1 million for Employer's Liability and State statutory requirements for Workers Compensation” (http://filmsf.org/insurance-requirements).

Comment: @BraddSzonye: That seems to be about filming, not photography.

Comment: Film SF handles both motion and still photography in the city, and the permit requirements are the same. Same is true in many other medium & large cities in California.

Comment: "All other types of productions, including but not limited to: commercial, digital media, student, corporate videos, PSAs, advertisements, feature films, independent films, television episodes, short films, web content and **still photography,** all require permitting through our office." (http://filmsf.org/permit-faqs)

Comment: In the above situations, Having insurance is a requirement to get a permit. 
Having insurance itself is not a legal requirement. The permit itself is only required in very specific situations. Therefore I stand by my answer.

Comment: I can’t speak for the UK, but in my experience as a photographer in California, _most_ cities here require permits and/or insurance for _all_ “professional” photography, which they typically define as anything involving a tripod. Usually, the consequences are simply being asked for the permit and then ordered to leave if you don’t have one, but that’s going to ruin any pro job you’re on. (I suspect that this is also true in at least some parts of the UK too, as I have seen that scenario play out on a UK-based vlog that I watch.)

Comment: Here’s an even clearer example from the city of San José: “Prior to commencing any filming or photography activity on public property, production companies must provide to the City of San Jose’s Office of Risk Management a valid Certificate of Insurance showing the following:
Commercial General Liability: minimum $1,000,000 combined single limit per occurrence for bodily injury and property damage including products and completed operations...” (https://www.sanjose.org/media/film-office/permits-insurance)

Answer (score 2):

As a professional you will be liable for your actions or negligence.   Just like anyone else!  If you're just wandering around with a camera, I wouldn't fuss too much.  If you're setting up a load of lighting equipment, in a space open to everyone, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

That was a good question - dido congrats! I joined the [PPA](https://www.ppa.com/) - Professional Photographers of America...I am sure the U.K. has something similar. Then you can get liability insurance - some venues won't allow you to shoot without it. I paid $256.00 for the year and when I shoot at a hotel or establishment I request a certificate from my producer to add the name of the business as the certificate holder which is good for a year.

Comment: "Libel Insurance"?  Surely there can be no such thing!  Or do you mean PII?